# HSQLDB startup DDL script

Tags: hsqldb

What is a good way of executing the DDL for a in-process HSQL database on the startup of the application?

I thought of selecting from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and if the count is zero, then i'd only execute my DDL script.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the database metadata is always a good way to find out if your tables have already been created. INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES reports some system tables and view as well as user tables, therefore you should select the name and schema of one of your application's tables to check the count.